# How do get pytest to do discovery based on module name, and not path

Tags: pytest

I'm looking at moving from `unittest` to `pytest`. One thing I like to do, is to do a `setup.py install` and then run the tests from the installed modules, rather than directly from the source code. This means that I pick up any files I've forgotten to include in `MANIFEST.in`.

With `unittest`, I can get the test runner to do test discovery by specifying the root test module. e.g. `python -m unittest myproj.tests`

Is there a way to do this with `pytest`?

I'm using the following hack, but I wish there was a built in cleaner way.

```
pytest $(python -c 'import myproj.tests; print(myproj.tests.__path__[0])')
```

Comment: `pytest --pyargs myproj.tests`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Tests as part of application](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-as-part-of-application-code) section of [pytest good practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) says if your tests are available at `myproj.tests`, run:

```
py.test --pyargs myproj.tests
```

Answer (score 0):

With pytest you can instead specify the path to the root test directory. It will run all the tests that pytest is able to discover. You can find more detail in the [pytest good practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html)

Comment: I know that. That does not answer my question.